# Loaded latest 3 items by ID into homepage

Tags: asp.net

I have a home page where I want it to display news items from the database. I have configured it so that it has one row and there columns.

Example:

```
Column1              Column2               Column3
Latest News Item     2nd latest news item  3rd latest news item
```

When my page loads it doesn't retrieve any information from the database. I also don't have it so retrieve the latest or 2nd or 3rd latest, I can still trying to configure this.

I have two queries, 
  1. How to retrieve one item into a column 2. How to code for the latest new item.

My aspx page is configured as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
            <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
            <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
            <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

My aspx.cs page is configured as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetNewsList();
}

private DataTable GetNewsList()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    string query = "SELECT [Id], [Title], [DatePosted], [NewsContent] FROM [News] ORDER BY [Id] DESC";
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
    connection.Close();
    return dataTable;
}
```

My database table is configured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[News] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]       NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [DatePosted]  DATE           NOT NULL,
    [NewsContent] NTEXT          NOT NULL,
    [IsRead]      BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your method for retrieving the DataTable looks incorrect. The below code will fill a datatable and by using `using`, disposed objects and closes the connection.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
{
    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

In your case this would be

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Id], [Title], [DatePosted], [NewsContent] FROM [News] ORDER BY [Id] DESC", connection))
```

UPDATE

Are you binding the DataTable to a Repeater (or other control) like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
                    <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
                    <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2><%# Eval("Title") %>
                    <small><%# Eval("NewsContent") %></small>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Code behind

```
Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
//or
Repeater1.DataSource = GetNewsList();

Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi VDWWD, Thanks for your response. I have it configured as you said. My aspx.cs page only has the information you have above in the page load. For this line, using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection)) I am getting the error "The name query doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: The query is your own string variable: `string query = "SELECT [Id], ...`

Comment: Sorry. I'm completely lost, I don't understand. I am only new to all this.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. The error is no longer there but it doesn't retrieve the data from the table unfortunately.